# Excel VBA Loop Msg

Tags: excel, vba

I new to writing code. I'm working with Excel 2016.

Here is what I am trying to accomplish: I have multiple Excel workbooks with one sheet in them. I am trying to consolidate all of them into just one workbook.

I'm getting the error msg

> "Compile error: Do without Loop"

Any suggestions and/or help welcomed. Thank you in advance.

```
'Description: Combines all files in a folder to a master file.

Sub MergeFiles()

    Dim path As String, ThisWB As String, lngFilecounter As Long

    Dim wbDest As Workbook, shtDest As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet

    Dim Filename As String, Wkb As Workbook

    Dim CopyRng As Range, Dest As Range

    Dim RowofCopySheet As Integer

    RowofCopySheet = 2 ' Row to start on in the sheets you are copying from

    ThisWB = ActiveWorkbook.Name

    path = Environ("userprofile") & "\Desktop\TEST\"

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set shtDest = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)

    Filename = Dir(path & "\*.xls", vbNormal)

    If Len(Filename) = 0 Then Exit Sub

    Do Until Filename = vbNullString

        If Not Filename = ThisWB Then

            Set Wkb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=path & "\" & Filename)

            Set CopyRng = Wkb.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(RowofCopySheet, 1), 

            Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count, ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count))

            Set Dest = shtDest.Range("A" & 

            shtDest.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row + 1)

            CopyRng.Copy Dest

            Wkb.Close False

        End If

        Filename = Dir()

End Sub
```

During the Debug it stops at `"Sub MergeFiles()"` and doesn't go any further.

Comment: You need a `Loop` statement to close your `Do Until` loop. See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/doloop-statement).

Comment: Your error message tells you the issue - you have a Do Until, but no end to your loop

Comment: Please learn to properly indent your code, so you can see the flow of execution more easily. It will help you spot this sort of issue.

Comment: Using indentation (and a better use of white space between lines -- a blank line between every line instead of just between logical units is a poor choice) would make your code both easier to read and even easier (in the sense of less debugging) to write.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon- thanks for the website, I used it, worked wonderful!

Answer (score 0):

I have put in an edit to your question to make it more readable,

```
            End If
        Filename = Dir()
    Loop                            ' <--------------- Add this statement
End Sub
```

Do loops need to be closed. By indenting `if` statements and loops it is much easier to read your program and understand what it going on.

Comment: `Filename = Dir()` after the loop makes little sense. The `Loop` should go after.

Comment: @JohnColeman That is true. Hopefully the edit will be approved soon.

Comment: But you can edit your own answer. If the loop doesn't modify `Filename` it will be an infinite loop

Comment: @John thanks I found that out when it only looped one file 6 plus times.

Comment: @Deepstop- Thanks I added the Loop below the Filename=Dir() At least I got movement within the VBA!

Comment: Don't I have to add a stopping point once it goes through all the files in the folder?